# Segmentation fault when calling fgets in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I am writing a function in my C code, and my function is asked to search randomly for a word in file composed from a given number of characters. 
Here is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "time.h"
#include "string.h"
void ExtMot(char nom, char *s[80], int n )
{
    FILE *fp ; 
    int i=0, j=0,x ;
    int taille= n  ;
    srand (time (NULL)) ;
    fp = fopen (nom,"r") ;
    while (fgets (s, 80, fp))
    {
        i++ ;
    }

    printf (" enter the size ") ;
    scanf ("%d",&taille) ;
    do
    {
        x= rand ()* rand() % i ; 
        rewind(fp);  
        while (fgets (s, 80, fp))
        {
           j++ ;
           if (j==x) break ;
        }
        s[strlen (s)]='\0' ;
        if (strlen (s)-1 == taille )
            break ;
        else
            j=0 ;
    } while (1) ;
    fclose (fp) ;
}


void main ()
{
   char mot[80];
   ExtMot("C:\\Users\\asus\\Desktop\\c_projet\\hello\\projet.txt",*mot,6);
   printf ("%s",mot);
}
```

I debugged my code and I got a segmentation fault error while calling the fgets function and the console application crashes. Can someone help me identifying the error?

Comment: That shouldn't even compile. Your call to `ExtMot` is a type error.

Comment: ... the `fopen` call is also a type error. And so is the `fgets` call. Are you just ignoring all compiler diagnostics?

Comment: `s[strlen (s)]='\0' ;` is a no-op.

Comment: @melpomene: what do you mean by no-op?

Comment: You haven't answered my question: Are you just ignoring all compiler diagnostics?

Comment: @BenHmida No operation

Comment: `char *s[80]` is an array of 80 pointers to `char`; not a pointer to an 80-character buffer.

Comment: Wow you need to learn basic C like compiling.

Comment: @BenHmida: a no-op is an instruction that accomplishes nothing. In this case, there's no point in setting to NUL the position in a string returned by `strlen`, since `strlen` itself relies on the NUL terminator to calculate the length of a string, so `s[strlen(s)]` is already NUL by definition.

Comment: Just take the compiler's warnings serious.

Answer (score 2):

I am wondering how your code was able to compile (if at all). You should have been getting warnings left and right for these type errors. The following adjustments should make your code compile (I compiled with `-Wall`), but I can't attest to the reliability of it as I don't know your `hello\projet.txt` file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
// these headers were wrapped in quotes "", instead of angle brackets <>

void ExtMot(char *nom, char *s, int n) {
    FILE *fp;
    int j = 0, i, x;
    int taille = n;
    srand(time(NULL));
    if (!(fp = fopen(nom, "r"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
    // always check if the result of fopen == null

    for (i = 0; fgets(s, 80, fp); i++)
        ;

    // rest of the code here...
}

int main(void) {
    char mot[80];
    ExtMot("C:\\Users\\asus\\Desktop\\c_projet\\hello\\projet.txt", mot, 6);
    printf("%s\n", mot);
    return 0;
}
```

You were trying to include C standard library headers with double-quotes, instead of angle brackets like you're supposed to. You only use double-quotes for includes if the header files are in the same directory as the source file. You seem to have the right idea for the types in the arguments of `ExtMot()`, but it wouldn't have worked the way you expect it to. `char nom` is a single character. `char *m[80]` is an array of 80 pointers to chars, not an array of 80 chars.

`*mot` is a pointer to an array of 80 chars. `mot` is the array of 80 chars. So instead of sending the char buffer to `ExtMot()`, you were sending the location of the char buffer in memory, which will break your code (and should trigger warnings from the compiler). See my code above for how to pass strings to a function.

**EDIT:** Also, `void main()` is outdated, and awful practice. Always use `int main(void)`, and return 0, if you don't expect any command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

With `*mot`, you are passing a character value where a pointer is expected (actually your compiler should have warned you). Thereby you pass a "memory address" that does not point to valid memory, and the `fgets` then writes into such memory. Further, you pass the filename as a single character, where it should be a string. And always  check the return value of `fopen`.

Change your program as follows and at least this issue should go away:

```
#include <errno.h>

void ExtMot(char *nom, char *s, int n ) {
   ...
   fp = fopen (nom,"r");
   if (!fp) {
      fprintf(stderr, "error opening %s: %s", nom, strerror(errno));
      return;
   }
   ...
}

int main ()
{
   char mot[80];
   ExtMot("C:\\Users\\asus\\Desktop\\c_projet\\hello\\projet.txt",mot,6);
   printf ("%s",mot);
}
```

Comment: still have the same crush !

Comment: @BenHmida Wow, sounds like you need to get over her

Comment: @stackptr - It could be a him?!